# Can I validate a field against a field in a related entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, fluentvalidation

I have a Project:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentProjectId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Deadline { get; set; }

    public Project ParentProject { get; set; }
}
```

And when I enter a date for `Deadline` on a child project, I would like to ensure that it is not greater than the `Deadline` of the parent project.

I am registering the validator in Startup.cs like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IValidator<Project>, ProjectValidator>();
```

I tried this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Deadline)
    .LessThanOrEqualTo(x => x.ParentProject.Deadline)
    .WithMessage("The deadline cannot exceed the deadline of the parent project.");
```

But I get

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is of cource because the parent project is not loaded at the time of validation.

How can I get it to work?

**Update**

I made this workaround:

In the controller POST method:

```
DateTime? parentProjectDeadline = await db.Projects
    .Where(p => p.Id == project.ParentProjectId)
    .Select(d => d.Deadline)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
if (project.Deadline > parentProjectDeadline)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Deadline", "The deadline cannot exceed the deadline of the parent project.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**.When**

You could rule out the case that the parent project is not loaded at validation time.

```
RuleFor(x => x.Deadline)
.When(x => x.ParentProject != null)
.LessThanOrEqualTo(x => x.ParentProject.Deadline)
.WithMessage("The deadline cannot exceed the deadline of the parent project.");
```

**Why is it not loaded?**

Can you explain how the ParentProject is not loaded "at validation time". Shouldn't a call to its getter always load and return it , given `_id` has a value?

Comment: `.When()` at least got rid of the error message. But that only means that the validation is not being run. The `ParentProject` is not a part of the model being sent from the form to the POST-method. The field `ParentProject.Deadline` is part of the form, and the value is there.

Comment: Hmm. In that case, you should not check it this way. You are defining a Rule for Project, in which the ParentProject, when present, can not have a earlier deadline than the subproject. If your Project instance doesn't even have a ParentProject (according to model), but instead, you want to check against some Value delivered from a form POST, you can not use the fluent API here but need to make input Validation in the POST Controller. The fluent API validators are here to validate the models consistency, not the inputs consistency.